# how to filter from multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get results from firstname or lastname,
current behaviour gives me results from firstname only. Or a better approach to this using `filter()` :) should not be case sensitive too

```
const people = [
      { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
      { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
      { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'bob', status: 'complicated' },
    ]

    const searchString = 'bob'

    const found = people.filter(
      (person) => new RegExp(searchString, 'i')
        .test(
          person.firstName || person.lastName
          ))

    console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the first argument that is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0` or `""`), so this searches for `bob` in `person.firstName` only.

You need to do two separate searches. To avoid repeating yourself, store the regexp object in a variable:

```js
    const searchString = 'bob'
    const regexp = new RegExp(searchString, 'i')

    const found = people.filter(
      (person) => regexp.test(person.firstName) || regexp.test(person.lastName)
    )

    console.log(found)
```

Comment: it's not just a case of "repeating yourself" - the original code would create a brand new `RegExp` object for every element in the array.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: most refactoring of this nature will also lead to optimisation.

Comment: @Thomas how about if I search `Bob Smith` it returns nothing....how can I combine the two terms in search?

Comment: @BizMAN that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const people = [
      { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
      { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
      { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'bob', status: 'complicated' },
    ]

    const searchString = 'bob'

    const found = people.filter(person =>
      (person.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
       person.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchString))
    )

    console.log(found)
```

Alternative solution without using Regex is by converting to lowercase using `toLowerCase` and using `includes` to search of substring existence

Comment: `filter` functions should return `true` or `false`, not the object. It works the way you wrote it, but is a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Or use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const found = people.reduce((acc, n) => {
  if (
    n.firstName.toLowerCase() === searchString
    || n.lastName.toLowerCase() === searchString
   ) {
    acc[n] = acc.push(n);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: How does this perform compared to regex solutions?